# 'auto contrast' text color in a gridview?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, devexpress

I have a (DevExpress) GridView with which I programmatically set background and text colors based on certain criteria. There are some circumstances where the background and text colors turn out to be very similar, making the text hard to read. What is the best way to ensure that there is always a contrast between the two colors? And is there a way to do this automatically with the DevExpress control?

Thanks.

Comment: I hope you can find an answer here: [How do I invert a colour / color? (C# .net)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165107/how-do-i-invert-a-colour-color-c-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this

```
    private Color GetContrastedColor(Color colorToContrast) {

        var yiq = ((colorToContrast.R * 299) + (
            colorToContrast.G * 587) + (
            colorToContrast.B * 114)) / 1000;

        return (yiq >= 128) ? Color.FromArgb(40, 40, 40) : Color.WhiteSmoke;
    }
```