# How does on-screen color inversion work in OS X?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, colortransform

This is what OS X's built in color inversion feature can turn your screen into:

[image]

It can invert all colors, turn them grayscale, adjust contrast. Now I want to build my own implementation and therefore need a professionals' advice.

Inability to capture inverted screen made me thinking that inversion is a sort of an adjustment layer, that resides above all windows and simply is not exposed to the interaction events. Is that so? Is it done via OpenGL libs?

I don't look into actual coding help, but rather a design/approach on solving the problem. In my goal app I will need to define output color diapasons and apply color transformation rules (input => output).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way Mac OS does the color inversion is (probably) by using [Quartz Display Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html) to modify the graphics card's gamma table.

Graphics cards have two of these tables to modify color output after composition into the final frame buffer. One of them can be modified by applications to alter the way the screen shows any RGB value.

Here's code to invert the display:

```
//ApplicationServices includes CoreGraphics
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    CGGammaValue table[] = {1, 0};
    CGSetDisplayTransferByTable(CGMainDisplayID(), sizeof(table) / sizeof(table[0]), table, table, table);
    sleep(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting! I was not aware of this.

Comment: How can I make the effect permanent (so the colors remain inverted even after this app exits)?

Answer (score 5):

To some degree, you can do this with Core Image filters. However, this is private API, so you need to be careful because these things might change or go away in future OS X releases and you obviously cannot submit your app to the App Store. <s>I don't think something like this is possible with public APIs.</s>

***Edit:*** See Nikolai Ruhe's answer for a better method that uses public APIs. You can do some things with Core Image filters that you couldn't do with a gamma table (e.g. applying blur filters and the like), so I'll leave my answer here.

Here's an example of how to invert what's behind a window:

```
//Declarations to avoid compiler warnings (because of private APIs):
typedef void * CGSConnection;
typedef void * CGSWindowID;
extern OSStatus CGSNewConnection(const void **attributes, CGSConnection * id);
typedef void *CGSWindowFilterRef;
extern CGError CGSNewCIFilterByName(CGSConnection cid, CFStringRef filterName, CGSWindowFilterRef *outFilter);
extern CGError CGSAddWindowFilter(CGSConnection cid, CGSWindowID wid, CGSWindowFilterRef filter, int flags);
extern CGError CGSSetCIFilterValuesFromDictionary(CGSConnection cid, CGSWindowFilterRef filter, CFDictionaryRef filterValues);

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self.window setOpaque:NO];
    [self.window setAlphaValue:1.0];
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.0 alpha:0.1]];
    self.window.level = NSDockWindowLevel;

    CGSConnection thisConnection;
    CGSWindowFilterRef compositingFilter;
    int compositingType = 1; // under the window
    CGSNewConnection(NULL, &thisConnection);
    CGSNewCIFilterByName(thisConnection, CFSTR("CIColorInvert"), &compositingFilter);
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
    CGSSetCIFilterValuesFromDictionary(thisConnection, compositingFilter, (CFDictionaryRef)options);
    CGSAddWindowFilter(thisConnection, (CGSWindowID)[self.window windowNumber], compositingFilter, compositingType);    
}

@end
```

(adapted from [Steven Troughton Smith's article here](http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2008/03/using-core-image-filters-onunder.html))

[image: screenshot]

The effect isn't perfect because for some reason it's necessary that the window has a background color that isn't fully transparent, but it's pretty close.

To affect the whole screen, you could create a borderless window that has `ignoresMouseEvents` set to `YES` (so you can click through it).

You can experiment with other filters, but not all of them may work for this. There's some info about the `CGS...` functions in this reverse-engineered header: http://code.google.com/p/undocumented-goodness/source/browse/trunk/CoreGraphics/CGSPrivate.h

Comment: Thanks. Very useful. Wether this is done with a private or public API it's still an API, which is the C (Objective-C) based anyway. Then I suppose going down the rabbit hole is something what I seek. An extra thanks for the article link.

Answer (score 3):

The way OS X itself does it is through a set of undocumented CoreGraphics API calls. I don't think they're declared in any official header file, but you can always just declare the prototypes yourself.

```
// clang -g -O2 -std=c11 -Wall -framework ApplicationServices

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

CG_EXTERN bool CGDisplayUsesInvertedPolarity(void);
CG_EXTERN void CGDisplaySetInvertedPolarity(bool invertedPolarity);

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    bool isInverted = CGDisplayUsesInvertedPolarity();
    printf("isInverted = %d\n", isInverted);

    sleep(2);
    CGDisplaySetInvertedPolarity(!isInverted);
    printf("Polarity is now: %d\n", CGDisplayUsesInvertedPolarity());

    sleep(2);
    CGDisplaySetInvertedPolarity(isInverted);
    printf("Polarity is now: %d\n", CGDisplayUsesInvertedPolarity());

    return 0;
}
```

There are similar API calls for other accessibility features, such as grayscale:

```
CG_EXTERN bool CGDisplayUsesForceToGray(void);
CG_EXTERN void CGDisplayForceToGray(bool forceToGray);
```

Comment: would there be any way to simulate what CGDisplayForceToGray does with CGSetDisplayTransferByTable?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165107/how-do-i-invert-a-colour-color-c-net) article explains how another user inverted his colors, however that wouldn't be an overlay, it would still accomplish your goal. Although this is in C# that would be your basic premise perhaps,a s those same ideas can work in Obj-c.

Basically this article says to convert your RGB color in HSV mode then invert the Hue value. To do this you must change Hue by 360-Hue and then convert back to RGB mode.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, this isn't exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @AleksandrMakov Ok, I will see what else exists.

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) for you to summarize the linked material here. Otherwise, the answer is at risk of losing its usefulness due to link rot.

Comment: @JoshCaswell KK, I will fix this. Better?